# XSL resolve reference

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MYDATA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item id="a01">
        <NAME>name of item a1</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="a02">
        <NAME>name of item a2</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="a03">
        <NAME>name of item a3</NAME>
    </item>
    <owner>
        <name>Max</name>
        <owns>
            <property prop_id="a01">
                <DATE_BOUGHT>1</DATE_BOUGHT>
            </property>
            <property prop_id="a02">
                <DATE_BOUGHT>2</DATE_BOUGHT>
            </property>
        </owns>
    </owner>
    <owner>
        <name>Anna</name>
        <owns>
            <property prop_id="a01">
                <DATE_BOUGHT>3</DATE_BOUGHT>
            </property>
            <property prop_id="a03">
                <DATE_BOUGHT>2</DATE_BOUGHT>
            </property>
        </owns>
    </owner>
</MYDATA>
```

We have items and their owners; an owner can own one or more items. I Am trying to write an XSL stylesheet to export all items of one person (Max in this case). It works but I don't know how I can print the items name rather than just the reference id:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Max's items</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Max's items</h1>
                <h2>List of all items owned by Max </h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th align="left">Title</th>
                        <th align="left">borrowed since</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="MYDATA/owner[name = 'Max']/owns/property">
                        <xsl:sort select="DATE_BOUGHT"/>
                        <xsl:key name="item-by-id" match="item" use="@id"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="key('item-by-id', @prop_id)/NAME"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="DATE_BOUGHT"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So in the generated output, I don't want `a01` but the name of that item "name of item a01":

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
            <title>Max's items</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Max's items</h1>
            <h2>List of all items owned by Max </h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th align="left">Name</th>
                    <th align="left">DATE_BOUGHT</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a01</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>a02</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Declare a key `<xsl:key name="item-by-id" match="item" use="@id"/>`, then select e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="key('item-by-id', @prop_id)/NAME"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="@prop_id"/>`.

Comment: thanks @MartinHonnen, I added it above, but I can't seem to get it right. where do I have to declare the key?

Comment: Do a search for `[xslt]resolve "cross-references"`.

Comment: The key declaration needs to be used as a top level element i.e. child of `xsl:stylesheet`

Comment: ah yes indeed, I had tested in the template but not above. if you post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept